# Tracking down a You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So, I have inherited a project that is written in Angular which I personally have not used before. My JS in general isn't that great.

I'm curious if anyone could provide any tips in tracking down this type of error. The log outputs aren't much help, but I think I have the code that is affected. But, I'm not 100% sure. If it is in the code below, could someone tell me what I've done wrong?

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:6)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:40)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:13)
```

I believe the error is coming from these two blocks of code when trying to load the event data to populate a table:

event.api.js

```
  getEvents(retries:number=0): Observable<any> {
    let url = this.apiURL + 'events'
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers  = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers  = headers.append('Authorization', this.authService.getToken());
    
    return this.http.get(url, {headers} )
      .map(
        (data) => {
          return Observable.from(Promise.resolve(data['payload']['events']));
        }
      )
      .catch(
        (error) => {
          let errMsg: string;
          if (error instanceof Response) {
              const body = error.json() || '';
                const err = JSON.stringify(body);
              errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
          } else {
                errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
          }
          if(retries++ <= 20){
            return this.getEvents(retries);
          }
          else {
            return error;
          }
        }
      )
  }
```

eventlist.component.js

```
  onLoadTable() {
      if(this.authService.getToken() == null){
        return;
      }
    
      this.processing = true;
      this.errorMsg = "";
      
      this.api.getEvents()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.processing = false;
            this.dataSource.data = data;
            this.paginator.firstPage();
        },
          (err) => {
              this.processing = false;
              var errorReturned = (err.error != undefined && err.error['message'] != undefined) ? err.error['message'] : ""; 
              this.errorMsg = "Error while retrieving event list: " + errorReturned;
        }
    );
  }
```

Comment: it might be in subscribeTo.js or subscribeToResult.js, the stack doesn't show that you have a problem with the code you provided

Comment: Try converting `return Observable.from(Promise.resolve(data['payload']['events']));` line to `return Observable.of(Promise.resolve(data['payload']['events']));`